# Specify data type in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, types

I have an array which contains this

```
"postage_cost" => $customer[total_shipping_cost]
```

when I use `var_dump` I get

```
["postage_cost"]=>
  string(5) "34.54"
```

How can I declare that this is a float and not a string when making the array? I'm sending this array to a web service and I'm afraid there might be some data type confusion. The $customer result is from a MySQL request.

Comment: On a related note, don't store monetary values in floats due to their inherent imprecision.

Comment: You may also want to look at using a class with a setter rather than an array.

Comment: @deceze could you please explain more? the manual of the api says this value should be a float. what is the imprecision?

Comment: as long as you just convert it before sending to the API, you're okay. But you should not do floating point *math* with monetary values.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @fab Not really. Even just converting the value to a float means it needs to be presented in a float, which is inherently imprecise. It's not about doing anything with it, it's about the float type not being able to store all decimal fractions precisely. Your `34.54` may turn into `34.53999999999999999` just by casting it to float.

Comment: @deceze technically correct. But here we have this API that wants a float (sensible or not), it will hopefully treat it in the right way - if not, we as the consumer can't do much about it anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"postage_cost" => (float) $customer['total_shipping_cost']
```

Note that I added quotation marks to the key because i am to 99.999 % sure that you don't have a **constant** named `total_shipping_cost`. PHP is gracious about that but with activated error reporting, this would have been a **Notice: undefined constant**

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue! (as well as all those Notice: undefined constant I was having...)

Answer (score 2):

```
"postage_cost" => $customer['total_shipping_cost'] + 0.0
```

or

```
"postage_cost" => (float) $customer['total_shipping_cost']
```

Beware that I added single quotes around `total_shipping_quotes`. This is not mandatory but is considered better style than raw text ; it is slightly faster, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
"postage_cost" => floatval($customer[total_shipping_cost])
```